# Find text before a pattern but after last occurrence of another pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove a module out of a file containing a list of modules. My case uses verilog hdl language, however, the problem is language independent.

A sample of the file looks like this:

```
(* generic one *)(* generic two *)
(* generic three *)
(* generic four *)
module one
  wire a;
  wire b;
  wire c;
endmodule;

(* generic one *)
(* generic two *)
module two
  wire a;
  wire b;
  wire c;
endmodule;

module three
  wire a;
  wire b;
  wire c;
endmodule;

(* generic one *)
module four
  wire a;
  wire b;
  wire c;
endmodule;

module five
  wire a;
  wire b;
  wire c;
endmodule;
```

I would like to remove module four. This implies removing the generic declaration before `module four` all the way to `endmodule`.

My approach is to find the last `endmodule` which occurs before `module four`. A random number of lines can occur between the two and those have to be removed as well. How can I find these random lines?

I tried to use positive lookbehind to solve this problem. I am using python3 regex library.

The pattern I tried to use is:

`pattern = re.compile(r'(?:<=endmodule).*?module four.*?endmodule', re.DOTALL)`

The problem with this pattern is `(?:<=endmodule).*?` matches the first `endmodule` in the file all way to `module four`, rather than the last `endmodule` which occurs before `module four`.

Comment: One solution is to look for the generic definitions rather than the last `endmodule`. It would look something like `r' (\(.*?\)(\n)*)*module four.*?endmodule'`.
However, I'm more curious about solving the problem with non-greedy positive lookbehind.

Comment: A tempered greedy token will work   - `(endmodule;)(?:(?!module|module four).)*?module four.*?endmodule;` and replace with `\1`, see https://regex101.com/r/RBM8h9/2